# Anchor buttons need margins on sides

Tags: html, css

Here is an image of my issue:

[image]

If you look my buttons are aligned all the way to there respective sides. I need some marginning on the left and right sides so they aren't aligned all the way to there sides. **I tried adding margin-left and margin-right and it did nothing**

Here is my CSS:

```
.profileinfo {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #202020;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.profileinfo a {
        position: absolute;
        right: 30px;
        top: 34px;
        display: block;
        width: 260px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 18px 0 16px 0;
        font: 25px/25px '-apple-system',BlinkMacSystemFont,'HelveticaNeue',Roboto;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #13cc3a;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 10px auto;
        overflow: hidden;
}

a.genericbuttonright {
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 360px;    
}

a.genericbuttonleft {
        left: 0; 
        margin: 0;
        width: 360px;                  
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="profileinfo">
<h1></h1>
<br>
<a class="genericbuttonleft" data-ripple-color="#ffffff" onclick="animateripple(event,this)" href="/profile/search">Search Profiles</a>
<a class="genericbuttonright" data-ripple-color="#ffffff" onclick="animateripple(event,this)" href="/profile/create">Create a Profile</a><br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the left / right values.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KrGgyZ)

```
a.genericbuttonright {
        right: 10px; /* here */
        margin: 0;
        width: 360px;    
}

a.genericbuttonleft {
        left: 10px;  /* here */
        margin: 0;
        width: 360px;                  
}
```